Custom Google Login Button Not Triggering Authentication
I'm trying to implement a custom Google login button using the Google Identity Services SDK. I want to style the button myself, instead of using the default Google button. However, when I click on my custom button, nothing happens.
Here's the code I'm using:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Sign-In</title>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <script>
        function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
            console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
            // You can decode and use the JWT ID token here
        }

        function triggerGoogleLogin() {
            google.accounts.id.initialize({
                client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                callback: handleCredentialResponse
            });

            google.accounts.id.prompt();
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('loginButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
                triggerGoogleLogin();
            });
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="loginButton">Login with Google</button>
</body>
</html>


What could be wrong or what am I missing?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What I've tried:
Verified that the triggerGoogleLogin function is called when the button is clicked.
